# Why are multiple sql queries run in sequece and not concurrently?

Tags: go, mariadb, goroutine

I am running  mysql “select” queries in seperate go routines at the same time. However the mysql service seems to collect these queries, run them in sequence (not concurrently) and then returns all the resultsets at the same time and only after all the queries have been run.

My questions are:
1. Why are theses queries run in sequence and not concurrently?
2. Why does mysql wait until all queries have been run before returning the resultset for each query  at the same time (even though each single resultset belongs to a different go routine and supposedly also uses a seperate connection)?

Another thing: when I set “SetMaxOpenConns(2)” then it returns two resultsets at the same time. If set to 3,  3 resultsets are returned at the same time. However they are still always run in sequence.

Anybody know what is going on here?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var database *sql.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    databaseURI := "root:toor@tcp(192.168.200.10:3306)/ahc"
    database, err = sql.Open("mysql", databaseURI)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("DB Connection Established")
        //database.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
        //database.SetMaxOpenConns(2)
    }
}

func test(device string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println("Thread: " + device + " started")
    start := time.Now()

    var count string

    //using go-sql-driver
    sqlStatement, err := database.Prepare("select count(cpeName) from report where errMessage <> \"ok\" and cpeName = ? and jobID = ?")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer sqlStatement.Close()
    err = sqlStatement.QueryRow(device, "11534").Scan(&count)
    sqlStatement.Close()


    duration := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("Thread: " + device + " Duration: " + duration.String() + "\n")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var deviceList = []string{"xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-002", "xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-068", "xx-sgvn-ca-lug-ap-004", "xx-swrk-ca-vez-s-005", "xx-swrk-ca-vez-ap-006",    "xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-065", "xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-073", "xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-076", "xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-077", "xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-001"}
    total := time.Now()
    for _, device := range deviceList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go test(device, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    duration := time.Since(total)
    fmt.Println("\n\nTotal: Duration: " + duration.String() + "\n")
}
```

THis is the output

```
DB Connection Established
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-068 started
Thread: xx-sgvn-ca-lug-ap-004 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-065 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-073 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-ap-006 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-s-005 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-076 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-077 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-002 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-001 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-076 Duration: 7.291656143s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-002 Duration: 7.304134404s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-065 Duration: 7.307958641s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-s-005 Duration: 7.313591747s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-077 Duration: 7.313992638s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-ap-006 Duration: 7.314905664s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-001 Duration: 7.320466323s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-073 Duration: 7.322158337s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-068 Duration: 7.324745097s

Thread: xx-sgvn-ca-lug-ap-004 Duration: 7.326001783s



Total: Duration: 7.326096238s
```

When using database.SetMaxOpenConns(1), this is the output:

```
DB Connection Established
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-068 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-001 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-ap-006 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-065 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-073 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-002 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-077 started
Thread: xx-sgvn-ca-lug-ap-004 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-076 started
Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-s-005 started
Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-068 Duration: 1.131790286s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-077 Duration: 2.128919333s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-001 Duration: 3.073559464s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-073 Duration: 4.002964333s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-s-005 Duration: 4.932256684s

Thread: xx-sgvn-ca-lug-ap-004 Duration: 5.853361245s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-gen-s-002 Duration: 6.785042625s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-065 Duration: 7.705957815s

Thread: xx-swrk-ca-vez-ap-006 Duration: 8.633000734s

Thread: xx-leus-ca-ust-ap-076 Duration: 9.550948572s



Total: Duration: 9.551103129s
```

Comment: Are there multiple CPU cores available to your Go app and the MySQL server?

Comment: What makes you think the queries aren't run concurrently? Is it the fact that all of them are started before they finish? I'm not sure that's a valid indicator. If the roundtrip to the db is substantially more expensive then starting a new goroutine wouldn't the output look like what you have?

Comment: With a single connection you can only run one query at a time. With multiple connections the parallelism is determined by configuration and resources, and the order they'd be returned in would depend on configuration and the driver--if there's a discrete order I'd look at the MySQL logs and configuration first, but I don't know anything about the Go driver.

Comment: @scruffy Would you consider this sequential as well? https://play.golang.com/p/mzYwxmYYtpF

Comment: They obviously are _not_ run sequentially. The completions are obviously interleaved. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. The problem is related to the number of CPU Cores available and it seems that this cloud based mysql service only runs on one CPU Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple technique to see whether they are run in parallel or serially:  Have each connection do

```
SELECT SLEEP(1);
```

If parallel, the set won't take much more than 1 second.  If serially, then N seconds.

If they are run sequentially, but no output until all are finished, that would be a GO problem.

If your 7.3s is really parallel and 9.5 is serial, then that points out why it is not worth it to run things in parallel -- They will step on each other and not finish much faster.  The conflict could be CPU or I/O or mutexes or network or something else; it depends on the query.  (My `sleep` test is very non-invasive, yet takes a predictable amount of time.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great "sleep" tip. All results are in fact returned after 1 second. This helped me understand and define the problem I am facing.